# Sorting 2^30 number of 32 bit integers. Best solutions

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, computer-science

I have a file with 2^30 number of unsigned 32-bit integer values, I need to sort them, so I want to make the fastest algotithm to do it.  All  available processors need to be used and use not more that 256MB memory.

What I think now:
Max int value (for 32-bit integer) Sm= 2^32, lowest = 0. Available memory is M=2^28.

- Devide output file for

  Sm*(sizeof int)/M = 2^32*2^5/2^28 = 2^9 parts;
  each part size 2^32/2^9 = 2^23.

Firstly, write simple reader that reads int value from input file, checks in what range it situated, and put to tempfile with integers in this range. After that I will have 2^9 files:

```
1 file= Integers from 0:2^23
2 file = 2^23:2^24
3 file = 2^24:(2^24+2^23),
and etc...
```

- Make sorting with standard algorithms like qsort or pyramid sort (have any advises for this alogrithms?)

I can use here something like Python.multiprocessing for make parallel sort, but it needs safe calcuating available free memory before each process starts

What do you think about this approach? May be exists more clean and easier solution?

Comment: May I suggest that your best course of action is to try it and see how it works?

Comment: "All available processors need to be used". Why would you say that? Surely you just want the fastest solution. Why do you care how many processors are used?

Comment: @AndrewAylett May I suggest that trial and error is not the most effective way to solve algorithmic problems

Comment: @David Yes, may be it bad idea to use all processes and make better solution

Comment: is that 256Mb (mega **bits**) of 256MB (mega **bytes**)?

Comment: Reading, comparing and then rewriting all the data into new files to have a new input for running the alghorithm will hardy be the fastest way...

Comment: related excellent book: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Pearls-2nd-Edition-Bentley/dp/0201657880  BTW are the integers unique?

Answer (score 3):

1. Read whatever fits into your memory at a time (let's call that a block), sort it and write it back to disk (i.e. sort chunks of 256 MBytes)
2. open all blocks at the same time, reading the first n entries from each block and build a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) (where n is such that you fill your 256 MBytes)
3. fetch the minimum element from the heap (noting which block it came from), write it out to the destination file
4. read the next element from the same input block and add it to the heap and repeat the previous step until all data is processed

256 MBytes are 2^28 bytes or 2^26 (four byte) integers, so you should only need to sort 2^4 = 16 blocks.

Comment: Just so someone has pointed it out: this uses the filesystem as a sort of virtual memory, which depending on the nature of the problem could violate the 256mb limit. (If it's a real-world problem, it's probably fine, but if it's a homework problem, then it might not be allowed.)

Comment: what I described above can reuse the original file where the numbers are stored (unless of course, that's forbidden as well for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

"unsigned 32-bit integer values" is the key point here. You can sort that using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Wiki page provides full [example in Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Example_in_Python).

Since you don't have enough memory to sort it all at once, you have to divide the work into parts fitting memory, sort each one of them saving results to disk, then merge results in a manner similar to merge pass of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Merging does not require loading whole thing into memory, all you have to do is read from partials,  while writing final result.

Comment: It requires to load all list members to memory - it's impossible for 256 MB

Comment: @Rustem: No, merging does not require loading whole thing into memory, since partials are already sorted.

Answer (score 2):

1). split the integers into parts

```
a. [0, 2^20 - 1], [2^20, 2^21 - 1]....
```

2). for each part, you could calculate the count of each integers (something like radix sort), the time complexity of each part is the length of the part. And the space complexity is also the length of the part.

```
// for each part
int start = 0;      // the starting point of the part
int end = 2^20 - 1; // the ending point of the part
int *hash = new int[end - start + 1];
for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
    // read a integer val
    ++hash[val];
}
for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
    if (hash[i] > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < hash[i]; ++j) {
            // print i
        }
     }
}
```

3). since you have 256MB = 256 * 2^20 = 64 * 2^20(int), so you could handle 64 parts in parallel. And you could set 2^20 to other value if you want.

4). Anyway, the total time complexity of this algorithm should be O(n) + O(2 ^ 32), n indicates the number of the integers. When n is very large, near to 2^32, this algorithm works very well. In addition, this algorithm could be handled in parallel.

5). This algorithm don't need the merge process, since the parts are sorted.

6). The heap solution mentioned above seems NOT to be handled in parallel.

Comment: Is it ok? That each next part greater than previous in 2 -times.  len(0:2^20) = len(2^20:2^21) = 2*len(2^21:2^22) = etc...

Comment: Hi, Rustem, the length of each part is the same, but has no intersection among parts. I think you could have a try this method, the code should be simple, no complicated sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using MergeSort. A short description can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Merge sort is well suited for a parallel implementation and for memory constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Radix sort is often claimed to be O(n), but it's really O(nlogn), because it requires time proportionate to the number of digits in the largest number * the count of numbers, and the number of digits is going to tend to be log(n).

I'd suggest using a 3-level compound sort:

1. insertionsort for small sublists of length around 32 or 64 - benchmark to find what's best - timsort covers this for you.
2. timsort or merge sort for large sublists up to your maximum amount of physical memory.  timsort is used by Python and Java for their sort methods, and is rather supernaturally fast, but it's a more complex algorithm than mergesort which matters if you're working in something like C - so if you just need something that works pretty well and is simple, go with mergesort.
3. In the large, use mergesort for merging the sorted files containing sorted large sublists.

Python's multiprocessing module allows you to store arrays of scalar types (like integers) in shared memory.  'just something to keep in mind.

Definitely have each core sorting a large sublist - that'll help a lot on a system with multiple cores.  Sometimes using a minheap for #3 is good, sometimes you're better off with just an array (for smaller numbers of large sublists).